# Difference between map, filter vs for and forEach and what would be the advantages of using map and filter over For and forEach loops?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have gone through the map and filter functionalities and got to know that there is some kind of differences and advantages over for and foreach.

Advantages:

1. No need to write too much of code and very clear understanding
2. Better performance compare to iteration

how map and filter will be the better performance ?

appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Comment: Where did you read that map and filter offer better performance? This article says differently: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Comment: forloop use index, foreach use key and value for the traversal. 
while mapreduce uses more complex nodes(mapper and reducer) which has the advantage of Sorting Searching Indexing and TF-IDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answer's actually explains the reasons. Here is a simple bench marking example. Use the link to run the test.

http://jsben.ch/cz0Cg

Posting the results in case if link expires.

**JS For Loop**

```
var foo1 = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction','present'];
for(var i=0;i<foo1.length;i++){
    console.log(foo1[i]);
}
```

Execution time : `677 ms`

**JS Map**

```
var foo2 = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
foo2.map((v,i)=>console.log(v));
```

Execution time : `686 ms`

**JS Filter**

```
var foo3 = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const result = foo3.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
```

Execution time : `259 ms`

> Execution Time given is when I tested, it is subject to change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @krishnadas, You are saying that for is better performance than a map right?

Comment: it's a judgment call. Different data can perform different.

Comment: I'm a little bit confusing to use for or foreach or map when I working with bulk amount of data which is better. if the map is better, then what type of functionality is using in the map to improve performance as I didn't get any clear explanation on it. @ Krishnadas

Comment: This is an example for a sample data, in this case for loop runs better than map. You can try the same with your actual data to see the difference. Also if you are in a unix env there is time command which you can use to find the time for individual scripts. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utime.htm. My intention was to measure the performance for a given input and see the result. For the actual data you need to find out which runs faster for you like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pros and cons in using `map` or `forEach`. They have their own **purposes**.

The main difference between this two methods is that `forEach` allows you to change elements of original array and returns `undefined` and `map` does not allow you to change original array and intended for making new array based on original one.

For example if you need to get array of user ids from array of users you should use `map` and if you need `console.log` something from each item of array, you should better use `forEach`.

As `javascript` is more functional language it preferably to use **non-mutating** functions from `Array.prototype` such as `filter`, `map`, `find` ect. It allows me to make code more readable and maintainable. I can write construction like tat one

```
arr.map(num => num * 2).filter(num => num > 5);
```

You can learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

P.S. for each `forEach` in my project there are 20 or more usages of `map` I avoid using mutable methods.